# Python command error while installing nodejs packages

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to install nodejs packages with command `npm install` but error appears:

```
Error:command failed c:\... Python\PYTHON. EXE - C import sys; "%s %s %s" % sys. Vwrsion_info
File <string>, Line 1
Syntax error invalid syntax
```

I have python3 installed. Maybe Python is needed? Any help? [image]

Comment: which OS? type this command 

which python 
(or)
where python

Comment: Windows 7 64bit

Comment: type where python in cmd

Comment: if it's installed in the path ... above line should work

Comment: Yes it works and gives right path

Comment: post complete error , maybe screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Add python to the windows path. You probably have python install for the current user rather than in the program files where it is looking for it.

search for "path" in the windows start menu and Click Environment Variables...

Select PATH in the System variables section
Click Edit
Add Python's path to the end of the list (the paths are separated by semicolons). For example:

C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python3.7...

You can find the path to the python exe by right clicking the shortcut and looking at the link address. You should add the python base folder and python\Scripts folder to the path

Comment: It's installed in directory 'Program files (x86).

Comment: OW. The actual error is the print error. It's a python2.7 package not a python3 one. install python 2. print statements require brackets in python 3